# dynamic date formats dependings on language and locale

Tags: ios, localization, nsdateformatter

Plz help me with date formatter: i need to change date formats depending on choosen language and choose format time 24 hour/12 hours, so a main trouble to dynamically update it. now i made it like

```
        [form setDateFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"]];
        NSDate *normalDate = [form dateFromString:time];

        if (normalDate == nil) {
            [form setDateFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a"]];
            normalDate = [form dateFromString:time];
        }

        [form setDateFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy %@",timeF]];
        normalStr = [form stringFromDate:normalDate];
```

but it's very bad method i think, pls help me to make better system, that will also work)

Answer (score 0):

I never tried, but you could try using the Localizable.strings file.
So when you localized your app, in Localizable.strings(English) you could have

```
"date_format" = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
```

while maybe in Localizable.strings(OtherLanguage) you put

```
"date_format" = "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a";
```

and in your DateFormatter you do

```
[form setDateFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"date_format", nil)]
```

Comment: I thought about this,but trouble, that user can set for example English and 12/24 hour format, so for every language there are 2 positions)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really want to do)

Consider using NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDateFormatter/dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:
e.g. with current locale value ([NSLocale curentLocale])
or use [dateFormatter setLocale:...], specifying selected language

```
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
```

and [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:...] to set it to  NSDateFormatterShortStyle, NSDateFormatterMediumStyle, or NSDateFormatterLongStyle

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 8, `DateFormatter` can handle this for you by calling [`setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter/1417087-setlocalizeddateformatfromtempla?language=objc)

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.formattingContext = NSFormattingContextDynamic;
[formatter setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
```